# Email Rendered ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email

There is an ASP.NET page that searches my database and inserts the results in a RepeaterList. The page is rendered for me, but I need to save the content that has been rendered into a variable. The user should be able to send the rendered content in an e-mail by clicking a button. How do I do this?

Comment: You want to send the entire page as an HTML e-mail? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yeah, is it! i want to get html to inser in my email body!

Comment: Couldn't you use jquery and essentially assign the html content to a variable that can be passed around?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to email the HTML contents of the repeater, you can do something like this:

```
System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);    
Repeater1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);

string repeaterHtml = oStringWriter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest way I've done so would be to do a postback on the email button, `override Render` and send your email there if the button had been clicked.

[Rick Strahl has an old, but good example](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Jun/08/Capturing-Output-from-ASPNet-Pages).